# Ionic device browser difference

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, device

I have my Ionic app all set up, however, it doesn't function like in the browser...for example, the background picture doesn't load. Does anyone know why?

Everything, including the API that app communicates with, is stored locally

[image]

Here is the **view**:

```
<ion-view title="Login" id="page2" hide-back-button="true" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" padding="true"
                 style="background: url('../img/loginBackground.jpg') no-repeat center;background-size:cover;">
        <form class="list">

            <style scoped>
                .inputCustom{
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                }

                .imgBack{
                    display: block;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    overflow: visible;
                    min-width: 60vw;
                    max-height: 60vw;
                    max-width: 60vw;
                }
            </style>


            <img src="../img/logo.gif" class="imgBack">

            <div class="spacer" style="height: 60px;"></div>

            <ion-list>
                <label class="item item-input inputCustom">
                    <span class="input-label">E-mail</span>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="" ng-model="user.email">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input inputCustom">
                    <span class="input-label">Lozinka</span>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="" ng-model="user.password">
                </label>

                <div class="animated flash" ng-show="validationBool"
                     style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; color: indianred">{{validationError}}
                </div>

            </ion-list>
            <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px;"></div>
            <a ng-click="signIn()" id="login-button1" class="button button-positive  button-block">Prijavi se</a>
            <a ui-sref="signup" id="login-button2" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Nemaš račun? Registriraj se</a>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Since its a strange problem I didn't know what to paste? View, controller, everything?

Comment: for now paste the code where you are using background and Is it working good on emulator or mobile?

Comment: Here, edited. It is working in browser as it should

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? the 'img' folder is in the 'www' folder right? Does the logo.gif show?

Comment: Of course. What does it mean if it "shows"?

Answer (score 0):

what I understand here is that you getting problem in showing up images in ionic. So here's the solution.
Problem in your code is here

```
background: url('../img/loginBackground.jpg')
```

You haven't gave a proper url for your image.This must be like this.

```
background: url('/img/loginBackground.jpg')
```

**Note:** No dots and your image would be in "www/img".
          Same for the **img tag**.

**EDIT:**
try this

```
.scroll-content {
background:url(/img/loginBackground.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
```

*and* remove style bavckground from ionic content.

Comment: When I put it that way it says in IDE "Cannot resolve directory". But it still shows in browser, but nothing changes on device

Comment: Well I don't know if everything else is working because my device doesn't communicate with localhost. I noticed now if I change path to /www/img/loginBackground.jpg that IDE shows it okay, but the browser shows the same image (or no image) that I see on device...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the preceding slash was causing the problem. The correct path is

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false" padding="true"
                 style="background: url(img/loginBackground.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;">
```

And for logo:

```
<img src="img/logo.gif" class="imgBack">
```